# How to get rid of this compiler warning?

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe7, xsuperobject

I have a few classes (of `TObject`) in Delphi XE7 (Firemonkey) which have a property `AsJson`:

```
uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, XSuperObject;

type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  public
    property AsJson: ISuperObject read GetAsJson;
  end;
```

However, the compiler is giving me warnings for these:

```
[dcc32 Warning] MyUnit.pas(383): W1009 Redeclaration of 'AsJson' hides a member in the base class
```

I'm looking in the base class of `TObject` and see no such thing, nor is it a valid field if I were to try to use it. I see nothing in the documentation about such a property. This only appears to happen if the property type is `ISuperObject` which is the latest version of `XSuperObject` (from SVN a few weeks ago at least). I also tried using type `Integer` and I get it too.

What does this warning mean in my scenario and how do I get rid of it?

**EDIT**

It appears to only happen when I have `XSuperObject` in the uses clause...

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  XSuperObject in 'C:\...\XSuperObject.pas',
  XSuperJSON in 'C:\...\XSuperJSON.pas';

type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FTest: Integer;
  public
    property AsJson: Integer read FTest;
  end;

begin

end.
```

Above example produces:

```
[dcc32 Warning] Project1.dpr(17): W1009 Redeclaration of 'AsJson' hides a member in the base class
```

If I simply remove `XSuperObject`, I don't get this warning. My copy of XSuperObject is a few weeks old.

Comment: If you get that warning for code as simple as what you show here (I don't) then that looks to me like a compiler bug (as in, some internal compiler table got corrupted). Do you also get this warning in an otherwise blank project?

Comment: The code in the question cannot give that error, assuming `TObject` is what we would expect it to be. Show a complete program.

Comment: Your edit is odd. You said you derived from `TObject`. Did you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, but it happens from any base class. I just did that to keep it minimal.

Comment: Why are there people still voting to close as "can no longer reproduce" when it's clear it can be? Accepted answer with the reason and everything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that `XSuperObject` declares a class helper for `TObject` this introduces an `AsJSON` property? That could explain the error.

**Update:** Sertac confirms in a comment that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Good guess: line [347](https://code.google.com/p/x-superobject/source/browse/trunk/XSuperObject.pas?spec=svn38&r=38)

Comment: Thanks, I never realized such a thing was even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Following code also triggers such warning. I suspect that you have `TObject` class redeclared somewhere.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  ISuperObject = interface
  end;

  TObject = class
  public
    function AsJSON: string; virtual;
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  public
    function GetAsJson: ISuperObject;
    property AsJson: ISuperObject read GetAsJson;
  end;

function TObject.AsJSON: string;
begin

end;

function TMyObject.GetAsJson: ISuperObject;
begin

end;

begin
end.
```

Comment: Please see my edit. It appears to be `XSuperObject` doing something.

Comment: Your answer can't be valid because you're making your own `ISuperObject` instead of using the actual `XSuperObject` library. Also, an answer cannot be based on suspicion. Answers on Stack Overflow need to be based on facts. Suspicion is very close to Opinion.

Comment: @Jerry The answer you accepted was based on suspicion. I just happened to have a lucky guess.

Comment: @David I didn't see that as suspicion, I thought you knew for a fact that XSuperObject had such a thing :-)

Comment: In your original question, you had three and half lines of code and all I could do is make educated guess about what might be going on. Granted my guess was wrong, and @David made much better one.